# Images not lining up correctly in horizontal list

Tags: html, css

What simple CSS mistake am I making?

I have a number of images setup in a ul as part of a gallery, each with a hover over text box

For everything except mobile breakpoints, I'd like them (the thumbnail versions) to line up 4 across.

By setting the width to 25%, I thought the following would handle that, but it's breaking it into 3 across with a bunch of space on the right side of the container - as if there was padding on the container or margin on the images forcing a new row.

There also appears to be a small amount of margin or padding on all sides of the image.  I've double checked each element through the browser and there is no margin or padding being applied from some other rogue style that I may have missed.

[JSFiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rmzz59m/)

**UPDATE:**  On my fiddle example, the hover-over text box is clearly going beyond the right edge of the image, but the css sets it's width at 100%.  Do I just have my positioning screwed up?

Link to live page at [www.deckdoctors.net/bay-area-deck-ideas.html](http://www.deckdoctors.net/bay-area-deck-ideas.html)

**Abridged HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul class="nivo">
        <li>
            <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
            <span>Some overlay text</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
            <span>Some overlay text</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
            <span>Some overlay text</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
            <span>Some overlay text</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Abridged CSS:**

```
#gallery {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    }

#gallery ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#gallery ul li {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#gallery ul li span {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:3;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #gallery ul li:hover span {
        visibility:visible;
        }


#gallery ul li a img {
    width:25%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't able to know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue:

Inline elements will have spaces after them which makes the last item on the row drop to the next line, so if you set a width of 25%, you'd need to counter for the spaces produced after each `<li>`.

A better way to do this would be to use float: left (which makes elements 'block-level') on the `<li>` and set it's width to 25%.

eg.

```
ul li {float: left; width: 25%}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/685m0b5z/

Also see this screenshot of it in action on your website:
[image]

Comment: Your suggestion for `float: left;` was exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fix: http://jsfiddle.net/3rmzz59m/1/

I believe the problem is related to the inline `li`s; sizing is a bit weird when it comes to inline elements. By changing them to `inline-block` and setting the width on the `li` elements instead, the extra spacing around them goes away.

Comment: The approach @thePav gave using floats works too, and for really old browsers that's better. However, floats add the whole clear problem as well, but that can be worked around.

Comment: You can counter the clearing problem by using {overflow: hidden} and {height: 1%} for old IE browsers - It's all mentioned in the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: @jacob - You're definitely at the root of the problem, but I tried simply using the inline-block and setting the li width and was still getting the issue.  I'd like to better understand what's going on there, but in interest of not staring at this any longer, I'm using the float as thePav suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width of images 24% instead of 25%

```
#gallery ul li a img {
    width:24%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

also set text-align:center for Gallery:

```
#gallery {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3rmzz59m/2/

Comment: I would not recommend this; on really wide displays, that 4% can be noticeable. `24.99%` could work if you have no other options, though.

Comment: @Jacob I tested it using zooming in Chrome, and it gives what I think suitable results i.e for my screen at 110% zoom it gives three columns. It is 15" laptop screen.